# SQLite Class Not Found Exception - Maven Project using Tomcat

Tags: java, database, sqlite, maven, tomcat

I am trying to implement a database into a maven project. I decided to use SQLite, I got it working in a separate program so thought it should be no problem to integrate it into this project.

I am getting the Exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.sqlite.JDBC
```

on the line

```
Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
```

All the stuff online and here talks about adding the jar files, but I am sure I have added it properly, it is in my referenced library in eclipse in the same project. Done the same way I done it on the project it does work on.

I will post the class where it is happening and hopefully someone can help. I dont think there is any point in posting other classes?

```
import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import Assignment.rest.model.CD;
public class CDRepositoryStub implements CDRepository {
    private static Connection con;

    private void getConnection() throws ClassNotFoundException, SQLException {
        Class.forName("org.sqlite.JDBC");
        con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:sqlite:C:\\Users\\Mick\\Desktop\\Year 4\\New folder (2)\\restDatabase.sqlite");
    }

    @Override
    public void create(CD cd) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        //should issue a insert statement to the db
        try {
            if (con == null) {
                getConnection();
            }
            PreparedStatement prep = con.prepareStatement("INSERT INTO data values(?,?,?,?);");
            prep.setString(1, cd.getId());
            prep.setString(2, cd.getTitle());
            prep.setInt(3, cd.getDuration());
            prep.setString(4, cd.getArtistName());

            prep.execute();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println("Exception caught " + e);
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Maven by default doesn't package dependencies inside the built-artifact. You have to explicitly mention that with  `assembly-plugin` or anything similar. If it's a webapp, you can copy the driver jar to the container's  lib directory. However, attaching the full pom would help

Answer (score 2):

Check that your dependency does not contain following statement

```
<scope>test</scope>
```

In it set by default in corresponding maven repository.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out you dont add jars the same in Maven, rather added it as a dependency in the pom.xml file. for anyone looking to do this the code is

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>org.xerial</groupId>
  <artifactId>sqlite-jdbc</artifactId>
  <version>3.16.1</version>
</dependency>
```

Also learned SQLite is not the ideal database to use in conjunction with Maven although it is fine for small projects etc.

Answer (score 0):

my solution: I run `mvn compile` and found that the sqlite-jdbc-[version].jar file's header is not right, which means the file has corrupted, after searched on network I force rm all directories in my .m2/repository and run `mvn compile` again, then it just compiled success.
Hope to help someone confused by the same unusual problem for so long.